# Android studio HINT text design

Tags: text, android-studio, placeholder, hint

So i am making an application for school. We have to use Android studio.
I want to make a bar with an icon and a placeholder (android: hint).
When i make this with this code, the hint text is at the left of the box.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/email"
        android:hint="Email" <---
/>
```

When i do it like this, the hint text is centered:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/email"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:gravity="center" <---
```

/>

How can i change the place of my hint text in other ways? I want it to be in 1/3 of the box.
But i have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dont use the gravity and use padding left :).

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/email"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:paddingLeft="70dp" />
```